# How to Change Screen Resolution Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, resolution

Let me tell you my problem. I want to change my screen resolution.
I can change it in an application but it changes only application's
screen. I wanna set system's resolution so it won't be important which
application is running on front. My device's resolution is set as 1280
* 720 p. Can I make it 1260 * 680? If it requires to make changes in
Android source code, I can. Just tell me where to change. Waiting for
your help.

Comment: I've come across [LCD Density](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/change-android-screen-resolution-with-lcd-density/), an app that does precisely that. Seeing if I can find out how it does it...

Comment: My problem is not density; it's about pixels. I want to change the real size of display.

Comment: How can you change resolution from java code ? I have device (android 4.4) that is connected to HDMI screen and I can use system settings > display > resolution > DACOUT_1080P_60 and monitor switches to 1080p but my application is always rendering to 720p even when I set resolution 480p

Answer (score 2):

[This thread on xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=637624) should set you on the right track.

Comment: Thx. But, I don't want to change the density. I wanna change real pixels to scale down the display.

Comment: @user511853 Changing real pixels would require ripping out the screen and putting a new one in. Changing [pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) is what you want, promise!

Answer (score 1):

Searching too a valid answer to this, but I have a lead to the solution :
*WARNING* Experimental buggy stuff :

```
/*
Requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
and android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS, thus it requires the app to be a system app.
 */
public void changeResolution(int x, int y){
    try { Class c = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
        try { Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("checkService", String.class);
            try {
                IWindowManager mWindowManager = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) method.invoke(null,Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
                try { mWindowManager.setForcedDisplaySize(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY,x,y);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }  catch (IllegalAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            catch (InvocationTargetException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Add a reduced AIDL version of IWindowManager to your project :
/app/src/main/aidl/android/view/IWindowManager.aidl

```
package android.view;
interface IWindowManager
{
    boolean startViewServer(int port);   // Transaction #1
    boolean stopViewServer();            // Transaction #2
    boolean isViewServerRunning();       // Transaction #3

    void setForcedDisplaySize(int displayId, int width, int height);
    void clearForcedDisplaySize(int displayId);
    void setForcedDisplayDensity(int displayId, int density);
    void clearForcedDisplayDensity(int displayId);
}
```

The app will require to be in the system apps folder.
It does something for sure, but right now it also lead to severe bugs.
Rebooting seems to cancel changes.

Waiting for feedback on this.

Answer (score -4):

If you are using Windows and know how to use JNI, Microsoft provides C++ Win32 function calls to do this:  [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413.aspx) and [EnumDisplaySettings()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611.aspx).

Comment: we are talking about Android.

Comment: Other users will come to this thread with non-Android searches on screen resolution. The functions I list will help them.